# This giant if statement feels wonky... how would you do this in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
for (NSString *metarComponent in self.readingComponents) {
    if ( [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"+"]
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"-"]
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"VC"]
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"MI"]
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"PR"])
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"BC"])
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"DR"])
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"BL"])
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"SH"])
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"TS"])
         || [metarComponent hasPrefix:@"PZ"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"DZ"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"RA"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"SN"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"SG"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"IC"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"PL"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"GR"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"GS"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"UP"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"BR"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"FG"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"FU"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"VA"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"DU"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"SA"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"HZ"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"PY"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"PO"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"SQ"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"FC"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"SS"])
         || [metarComponent hasSuffix:@"DS"]) {     
            [rawWeatherStrings addObject:metarComponent];
        }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to code for iOS 3, I suppose an `NSRegularExpression` would do wonders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create an NSSet of prefixes and an NSSet of suffixes, then use containsObject on these sets with the first character (also first two characters after reviewing your prefix set) and last two characters pulled out of the string in question, to check against the sets.  The lookup will be very quick.

Comment: You'd actually need to check both the first character and the first two characters, since prefixes can be one or two characters in the original if-statement.

Comment: Excellent point, I missed the fact the suffix could be anything but + or -.  Annotated.

Answer (score 1):

An array of prefixes and array of suffixes and two `for` loops should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Build a constant table of the prefix/suffix and a flag indicating which it is, then iterate over the table to check if it has the prefix or suffix.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *prefixes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"+", @"-", ..., @"PZ", nil];

NSArray *suffixes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"DZ", @"RA", ..., @"DS", nil];

for (NSString *metarComponent in self.readingComponents) {
    for (NSString *prefix in prefixes)
        if ( [metarComponent hasPrefix:prefix])
             [rawWeatherStrings addObject:metarComponent];
    for (NSString *suffix in suffixes)
        if ( [metarComponent hasSuffix:suffix])
             [rawWeatherStrings addObject:metarComponent];
}
```

Comment: No need to create `NSArray` for this.  C-style array should be sufficient.

Comment: Using an NSArray is a little bit easier to use and slightly less error prone.  The overhead in this case is very minimal.  If, in the future, it turns out to be a bottleneck, it can be changed.  Code first, optimize later.